# 21C XE Installation does not start on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, oracle-xe, oracle21c

I try to install Oracle 21C Express Edition on Windows 10 Enterprise(on virtual machine). But after setting installation directory, it does not forward more. "Next" click does not give any response or any error.

There was 11G XE before and also 11g clients. I uninstalled all of them. I restarted Windows. My user is added in administration group. Also, Weblogic is installed on Windows.
ORACLE_HOME and TNS variables don't exist in system PATH variables list.

We have similar copy of this VM which have similar config with this. I could install on other VMs but on this I could not.

I could not find any log about installation(C:Programs&files/Oracle/Inventory logs does not contain any log about this setup)

What can be the reason, do you have any idea?

Thanks and regards.

[21C XE Setup does not forward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzaG0.jpg)